# Updating a message while processing a method triggered by the tag "value" of a dataTable

Tags: jsf, page-lifecycle, tomahawk

I have a page with a Tomahawk datatable. On its "value" tag, i call a method that gets a list from some EJB and if it comes empty i have to display some message on the page. The logic works, it executes the method i created to display the message on the screen, but it won't render the message on the page. I am afraid this has something to do with JSF's lifecycle. Is there any workaround i can do in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approach is to make use of the `rendered` attribute.

```
<h:outputText value="List is empty" rendered="#{empty bean.list}" />
<t:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" rendered="#{not empty bean.list}">
    ...
</t:dataTable>
```

The `empty` EL keyword will evaluate `true` when `bean.list` is empty or `null`.

That said, doing EJB logic in a getter is pretty a bad idea. Getters are solely there to return data and can be invoked more than once in bean's life. Rather do EJB stuff in bean's `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that i use the same bean for 3 pages. This is the second page in the process, and i need the input from the first in order to call the ejb, that's why i thought about calling it on the get method. I guess i will create another bean then.... thanks.

Comment: If the list is dependent on the submitted data, then you should populate the list in submit method (the commandlink/commandbutton action method).